# Can jQuery change css style definition? (not individual css of each element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stylesheet

I haven't seen any docs saying jQuery can change any CSS definition such as changing

```
td { padding: 0.2em 1.2em }
```

to

```
td { padding: 0.32em 2em }
```

but either have to change a whole style sheet, or change class of each element, or change css of each element.

Is changing the style definition possible?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There is DOM access to stylesheets, but it's one of those things we tend to avoid because IE needs a load of compatibility cruft.

A better way would be typically be to trigger the change indirectly, using a simple class change on an ancestor:

```
td { padding: 0.2em 1.2em }
body.changed td { padding: 0.32em 2em }
```

Now just `$('body').addClass('changed')` and all the `td`s update.

If you really must frob the stylesheets:

```
var sheet= document.styleSheets[0];
var rules= 'cssRules' in sheet? sheet.cssRules : sheet.rules; // IE compatibility
rules[0].style.padding= '0.32em 2em';
```

This assumes that the `td` rule in question is the first rule in the first stylesheet. If not, you might have to go searching for it by iterating the rules looking for the right selectorText. Or just add a new rule to the end, overriding the old one:

```
if ('insertRule' in sheet)
    sheet.insertRule('td { padding: 0.32em 2em }', rules.length);
else // IE compatibility
    sheet.addRule('td', 'padding: 0.32em 2em', rules.length);
```

jQuery itself doesn't give you any special tools to access stylesheets, but it's possible there are plugins that might.

Comment: It's worth noting that IE (incl. IE10) does not preserve the original `selectorText`. Something written as `.foo.bar` in the CSS stylesheet might end up as `.bar.foo` in the DOM rule object. This makes "hunting for the right selector text" extraordinarily brittle.

Comment: @Tomalak: Right - and indeed, there is no requirement in the spec for `selectorText` to contain exactly the same string as the original selector. It's the same as `innerHTML` - the parser converts the source into a bunch of objects, and then reading the property results in a serialisation that is the textual representation reflecting the information the browser is using, but a serialisation that is not in any way guaranteed to be the same as the source. Consequently searching for exact `selectorText` is inherently unreliable.

Comment: The best part of this answer is: "A better way... class change on an ancestor"

Answer (score 29):

```
$('head').append('<style id="customCSS">td { padding: 0.32em 2em }</style>');
```

I added an id attribute so you can target and remove it when you no longer want that change to apply.

```
$('#customCSS').remove();
```

Comment: This adds and removes, but doesn't change

Comment: Include !important if you find there's no change because the existing css resides after the appended css.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a problem where I didn't know the width I wanted a class until it was loaded and did this.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    calcWidth = CalculateWidth();

    $('body').prepend('<style> .dynamicWidth { width: ' + calcWidth + 'px } </style>');
}
</script>
```

Note: it may matter where you put the script (prepend, append) depending on how you want the rules to 'cascade'.

Answer (score 3):

Now this is possible by using **CSS Variables**

CSS:

```
:root{
--my-padding: 0.2em 1.2em;
}

td{
padding:var(--my-padding)
}
```

jQuery:

```
let paddingX = 0.32
let paddingY = 2
$(':root').css('--my-padding',`${paddingX }em ${paddingY }em`)
```

Comment: Very helpful!  Nice to have a modern answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it just doesn't work this way...not sure any better way to explain it than that :)

jQuery was designed to work on elements...if you're doing this for testing, Firebug of the Chrome console are options though.

Something you *could* do, is have a server-side generated stylesheet, for example how [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) does it, and jQuery (or vanilla JS) dynamically adds that `<link>` into your header, something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="myCSS.php?tdPad=.32|2" type="text/css" />
```

If it was the last link, it'd override the previously defined style...in fact this is *exactly* how ThemeRoller works.