# Changing styles of page using JS and CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to CSS assigned inside the head tag using JS, its not working for IE any idea why? IE just show  "Unknown runtime error".

```
<html>
<head>
<style id="style_id" type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is the test Text</p>
</body>
<script>
    var st = document.getElementById("style_id");
    st.innerHTML = "p { color:red}";
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can jQuery change css style definition?  (not individual css of each element)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164740/can-jquery-change-css-style-definition-not-individual-css-of-each-element)

Comment: This is not trivial. See the linked dupe question for a good answer

Comment: Not getting..... do you agree with what @Chinmayee's answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript) one?