# How can I dynamically change css for html that is generated by javascript at runtime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some html that is generated programmatically using javascript at runtime.

I want to be able to dynamically change the css properties of this html
e.g.

```
  $(".pointsbox").css("background-color","green");
```

but it appears to not work as those html elements are not available at the time that the css change is called.

I am pretty sure I have managed to do this before but I've forgotten what the function is called.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You might want to check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3164861/441352

Comment: I don't think the two questions are similar at all, despite the wording being somewhat alike.

Comment: The effect he's after is covered by the same solution. To add some style to a potential future bit of HTML. If anything, I think the wording is different but it's the same basic problem: to want to dynamically change style much earlier than you're adding the DOM content. Going for some class on a parent rule, or modifying stylesheets are two of the most obvious approaches to this problem, I think.

Comment: Given the simplicity of this specific example, a CSS definition would suffice; I don't think there's a need to go modifying stylesheets using Javascript. I was looking at it more as a generic 'How do I interact with dynamically added elements?' problem rather than a 'How do I put a green background on dynamically added elements with a specific class?' problem.

Comment: Yeah, you're right that it's probably overkill, but it is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted code on how exactly you create your HTML elements, but it can be something as simple as this:

You can create an HTML element by passing HTML into the jQuery function right?

```
var new_element = $('<div>');
```

Well, you can treat that like any other jQuery object, and just manipulate its CSS right then and there.

```
var new_element = $('<div>').css('background-color', 'green');
```

Heck, you can even chain the *create*, the *css change* and the *DOM insert* in one call.

```
var new_element = $('<div>')
                      .css('background-color', 'green')
                      .appendTo('#container')
                      ;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are the [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events) - specifically the `DOMNodeInserted` event - that you *could* bind an event handler to. However, as the page I linked states, it's recommended that you don't because it has a serious negative effect on the performance of your page and the cross-browser support isn't particularly good.

An alternative is to simulate your own `DOMNodeInserted` event using a custom event. Essentially you bind a handler for a custom event (say `nodeinserted`) on the document, then trigger that event whenever you have code that dynamically modifies the structure of your page. Code might look something like the following:

```
$(document).on('nodeinserted', function() {
    $('.pointsbox').css('background-color', 'green');
});

function modifyPage() {
    // code to modify your page here
    $(document).trigger('nodeinserted');
}
```

Note that, with this approach, you'll need to modify **all** functions that add elements to the page to trigger that `nodeinserted` custom event.

Answer (score 0):

I use this. It ensures the DOM has loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //code here 
    $(".pointsbox").css("background-color","green");
});
```

Comment: this will not work if you are adding some element with class pointsbox after DOM has loaded. :(

Comment: How did this get an upvote when it doesn't answer the question at all?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist It seems Rowan's code is executing before the DOM has loaded. Does this not solve the issue?