# CSS global variables

Tags: css, sass, less

I have a css file that uses one color on many different elements. Instead of using jquery to dynamically change every element, I was hoping to be able to specify a global variable (example: `$color1`) that would set the color for me.

Here's an example below where the color #F54F36 is used in many different elements. I am currently using jQuery to dynamically change these elements but I would like to see if there is a way to define a global variable in CSS.

```css
::selection {
    background: #F54F36;
    color: #fff;
}::-moz - selection {
    background: #F54F36;
    color: #fff;
}#jpreBar, .patern span, .red, .nav - button span, .inner - overlay, .skillbar - bar, .serviseslider h3 span, .icon - holder, .subscriptionForm input#submitButton, #loadingProgress, .sepcolor, .quote - icon, .skillbar - bar, #facts ul li h6, #closeProject a, #ajaxpage a.lanch - project, #clientlist, #contact_form textarea: focus,
#contact_form input: focus,
.owl - theme.owl - controls.owl - page.active span,
.owl - theme.owl - controls.clickable.owl - page: hover span,
.slides - pagination a.current,
.slides - pagination a: hover,
.submit_btn: hover,
.resume - head,
.resume - line,
.resume - date,
.download - resume {
    background: #F54F36;
}.ajl,
.bigtext,
.sections - head,
.slides - container h1 span,
.error,
#options li: hover,
#options li.actcat,
.social - list ul li a: hover,
.num,
.project - description h3,
.project - details h3,
.subcribe div#error,
.subcribe div#success,
.smallicon: hover,
.footer,
.company - color {
    color: #F54F36;
}#team.content,
#options li.back,
#subscribe.content,
#prices.content {
    border - top: 2px solid#F54F36;
}#facts ul li h6: before {
    border - bottom - color: #F54F36;
}#testimonials.content {
    border - top: 2px solid#F54F36;
    border - bottom: 2px solid#F54F36;
}.actser: after {
    border - top - color: #F54F36;
}.inner a: hover,
.inner li.current a {
    color: #F54F36;
    border - right: 2px solid#F54F36;
}.customNavigation a.next - slide {
    background: #F54F36 url(.. / images / pl - small.png) no - repeat center;
}.customNavigation a.close {
    background: #F54F36 url(.. / images / close - white.png) no - repeat center;
}.customNavigation a.btn: hover {
    box - shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
    0 0 10px 10px#F54F36,
    0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}.triangle {
    border - color: transparent#F54F36 transparent transparent;
}.popup - gallery a span {
    background: #F54F36 url(.. / images / pl - small.png) no - repeat center;
}.social - list ul li.back {
    border - top: 1px solid#F54F36;
}.to - top: after {
    border - bottom - color: #F54F36;
}.flex - direction - nav.flex - next {
    background: #F54F36 url(.. / images / project - next1.png) no - repeat center;
}.flex - direction - nav.flex - prev {
    background: #F54F36 url(.. / images / project - prev1.png) no - repeat center;
}.right - date: before {
    border - right - color: #F54F36;
}.left - date: before {
    border - left - color: #F54F36;
}.resume - circle {
    border: 2px solid#F54F36;
}.resume - slider {
    border - bottom: 10px solid#F54F36;
}
```

Comment: Use LESS, SASS or Stylus :)

Comment: Is this a situation where there is a base .css file for the site and users of that site can choose to customize certain parts and each user might have different customization?

Comment: Are you asking about how YOU can have a variable (as the developer, in which case the answers like SASS make the most sense) or are you asking how the visitor to your site can set the background color on their end?

Comment: Is there a question here?  If you know that you need a CSS preprocessor, why didn't you read up on them or try one?

Comment: @cimmanon. I did not know I needed a CSS preprocessor and nowhere did I state I needed one. My question was pretty clear - How do I define a global variable in CSS. Next time please read up on the question before you make assumptions.

Comment: @bagofmilk The inclusion of the [sass] and [less] (both CSS Preprocessors) tags seem to imply that you have a pretty good understanding that's what's needed here.  Since that's the case, the next logical step is to *research* those technologies and see if they solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into Less or SASS precompiling.

Comment: If I used SASS. How could I have the user define what color they want and update the stylesheet?

Comment: for example. if I defined `$color1` in SASS to be 'red', but the user changed it to '#ff3636'. How would I update the SASS variable?

Comment: That is different then. You would need a backend service to return a style sheet based on query parameters that you could then reload. Have php, node, python, whatever return a dynamic stylesheet based on a GET request.

Comment: we can Create global variable in css see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262189/css-global-variables/37177559#37177559

Answer (score 1):

You can't create variables in CSS right now. You do get this functionality in a CSS preprocessor like SASS or LESS, but not at runtime (because it's a preprocessor).  You should continue to use Javascript to achieve this.

In the future, some of the goodness that SASS or LESS provides may be implemented into CSS4.. until then you can't achieve this in pure CSS.

You can't use Javascript to change class attributes either unfortunately, but, depending on your situation, some of the compromised solutions in this question may be helpful: [jQuery CSS: Dynamically change attributes of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477746/jquery-css-dynamically-change-attributes-of-a-class)

Comment: we can Create global variable in css see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262189/css-global-variables/37177559#37177559

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're asking about a variable for you, the developer to use, but one the end-user, the visitor, can set, correct?

If so, then you need to incorporate JavaScript into the mix.

Set up your classes so you have a class just for defining this color.

```
.userColor {/* put a default color here */}
```

In your HTML, you will then have:

```
<div class="class1 class2 userColor etc"></div>
```

Then you can use jQuery to change all elements with that class to have the color you want:

```
var = yourColorVariable // up to you how to set a value for this
$('.userColor').css('background',yourColorVariable)
```

If, on the other hand, you are asking how can a customer (say someone that bought your software to host it) set up their own custom color (ala a 'template' for their their business) you have a few options. The simplest is to let them define their own CSS for this class:

```
.userColor {/*let the customer modify this directly*/}
```

If you need them to do that only via some sort of admin tool, you'll want to use some back end code to write that to a variable in your db or a static .css file.

Comment: Thanks. But I already mentioned I'm currently using jquery to accomplish this. I might try adding more classes like you mentioned...

Comment: @bagofmilk oh! You DON'T want to use jQuery. I'd suggest removing the jQuery tag from your question. As other's have stated, there's no such thing as variables in CSS. You can use them as a developer in pre-compile tools like SASS, or via server side code that spits out CSS, but not in the browser.

Comment: we can Create global variable in css see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262189/css-global-variables/37177559#37177559

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS, **No need preprocessor like SASS or LESS**. Now css support Global variable. Simple example is shown below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
:root {
  --bigfont:100px;
}
#test{
font-size:var(--bigfont);
}

</style>
<body style="text-align:center;margin-top:60px">

<div id="test">Merbin Joe</div>

</body>
</html>
```