# Javascript changing stylesheet css property

Tags: jquery, css, rule

first of all my english is not so good but i believe it will be enough for defining myself.
In style.css file

```
div.myclass
{
    width:20%;height:350px;background-color:#097;float:left;margin-right:5px;
}
```

in html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
```

U see, i have this divs and i want to change them background image with jquery.

I tried to use .css() function for it

```
$('div.myclass').css({'background-image':'url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAEElEQVQIW2P8DwSMIMAABQA+HQQDNlbHLwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)'})
```

But function changing div to this

```
<div class="myclass" style="background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAEElEQVQIW2P8DwSMIMAABQA+HQQDNlbHLwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);"></div>
<div class="myclass" style="background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAEElEQVQIW2P8DwSMIMAABQA+HQQDNlbHLwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);"></div>
<div class="myclass" style="background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAEElEQVQIW2P8DwSMIMAABQA+HQQDNlbHLwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);"></div>
```

**I'm asking how can i change div css rule inside the stylesheet file**

```
div.myclass
{
    width:20%;height:350px;background-color:#097;float:left;margin-right:5px;
}
```

**to this**

```
div.myclass
{
    width:20%;height:350px;background-color:#097;float:left;margin-right:5px;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAEElEQVQIW2P8DwSMIMAABQA+HQQDNlbHLwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}
```

Comment: It's possible, but why would you want to? The end result is the same.

Comment: @Blazemonger http://tny.cz/c5e3796a check this text and u understand why i want to

Comment: That doesn't answer anything; there's no technical reason to use one approach over the other. [Gary Storey's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25389588/901048) is the approach you should probably use.

Comment: @Blazemonger i re-edit my question and how can i say, i think i cant clear define myself. becaue my english is not so good :/

Comment: why is my question is marked duplicated. i do not duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164740/can-jquery-change-css-style-definition-not-individual-css-of-each-element this is different question :(

Comment: Guys ur answer is not helping me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164740/can-jquery-change-css-style-definition-not-individual-css-of-each-element this answer for specific document.styleSheets[0], my class it be [1] or [2] or [3]. how can i find div.myclass inside of them

Comment: You can't actually change a CSS stylesheet using JavaScript; you can only add new styles to it. But later styles override earlier styles, so it's the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Since javascript is client-side and only runs after resources from the server has been retrieved, there is no way to alter the css file on the server (if that's what you're asking). Using the css() function will alter the inline styles, ultimately overriding any external style sheets.

This answers it well:
[Can jQuery change css style definition? (not individual css of each element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164740/can-jquery-change-css-style-definition-not-individual-css-of-each-element)

Comment: i tried but my browser have extension and they using css-file to. document.styleSheets[0]
u see, that zero is not global value and it can be a bug for some browsers

Comment: I'd suggest sticking to the inline css then. It will accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is you **shouldn't**.  You should use classes and swap them. But you could do this:

```
$('style').html('div { background-image: image.png; }');
```

Comment: i can do that but i write this: http://jsbin.com/fizimihizabo/1/edit sample for definig myself. i use the solution for other project

Comment: i re-edit my question, can you check it