# Dynamically delete a style from head tag with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, styles

I am dynamically creating a style like below and appending that to `<head>`

```
 $("<style type='text/css'> .HP{  background-color: "Red "} </style>").appendTo("head");
```

On the page I want to delete a particular css class and re-add with different value. How this can be done in JQuery.

Comment: Are you trying to [modify the stylesheet directly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3164740/645956)?

Comment: Just one rule, or that entire style element? (I notice the *example* has only one class rule, but...)

Comment: Side note: Color names don't go in quotes, and aren't capitalized: `background-color: red`

Comment: Was just dynamically adding one rule to <head>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add an ID to style attribute

```
 $("<style id='myStyle' type='text/css'> .HP{  background-color: \"Red \"} </style>").appendTo("head");
```

Then you can simply use ID selector with `.remove()` like

```
$('#myStyle').remove()
```

Comment: I just tried with .remove() but nothing happens, it still there, so i used $("#myStyle").html(""); after the .remove() and now i can see a change

Answer (score 2):

You can use [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css), no need to alter your main stylesheet like,

```
$('.HP').css('color','red !important');
```

The above will make the font color `red` for all elements having `HP Class`

```
$('.HP').css('background-color','green !important');// change your bgcolor red to green
```

And to remove the last added `style` try this,

```
$('head style:last').remove();
```

Also, if you are adding multiple Styles dynamically, then to remove specific Style give a `id` to style tag and [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove) it like,

```
$('#STYLE-ID-TO-BE-Removed').remove()
```

Comment: This adds an inline style, imagine if you add elements dynamically, every time you add at least one you will need to call the css() again. Doesn't seem efficient in that scenario

Answer (score 0):

Add ID to that style that you want to delete.
Then In JQuery use

```js
$("#styleId").remove();
```