# Unexpected behavior with class added by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A tale of two fiddles (please use the run button after the jsfiddle pages load for a clearer idea of what is happeneing).

[The First Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgkxgrhk/3/)

Dead simple:

```
$("body").addClass("noScroll");
alert($("body").hasClass("noScroll"));
$("body").removeClass("noScroll");
alert($("body").hasClass("noScroll"));
```

With this css:

```
.noScroll {
    background-color: pink;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 200px;
}
```

We have a class. The class is added to body, changing the body's appearance/behavior. The class is removed from the body and the body reverts to default. Working as expected.

[The Second Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgkxgrhk/2/)

```
$("body").addClass("noScroll");
alert($("body").hasClass("noScroll"));
$(".noScroll").css({
    "background-color" : "pink",
    "position"  : "fixed",
    "width"     : "100%",
    "top"       : "200px"
});
$("body").removeClass("noScroll");
alert($("body").hasClass("noScroll"));
```

No accompanying CSS this time, as it's added by jQuery, but otherwise pretty similar to above. Working to a point. CSS is applied, but it isn't *removed*. Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: `"When using .css() as a setter, jQuery modifies the element's style property."` --  [jQuery .css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Adding this because it addresses what I was trying to do. Though doing it appears complicated and is probably a bad idea. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164740/can-jquery-change-css-style-definition-not-individual-css-of-each-element)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the second fiddle, when you call css() on the `noScroll` selector, it applies those styles inline to the element with class `noScroll`. However, those styles are not preserved in a named css style.

So the code is actually working. It is adding a class `noScroll`, but no styles are affiliated with that class in the css. Also, it is removing that class, but the styles from the `css()` call stay because they were applied inline.

To get a better idea, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgkxgrhk/5/) where the inline style is removed manually at the end.

Comment: Which is pretty obvious now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Inline styles and CSS classes are two different concepts. Adding and removing one does not add or remove the other. Inline styles only override styles applied via classes.

The selector you used to find the element to apply the inline styles to does not get stored anywhere. So jQuery/the browser can't possibly know which inline properties to remove when you remove the class.

Answer (score 0):

You've applied inline CSS in the second example. This is equivalent to doing this:

```
<body style="background-color:pink; position:fixed; width:100%; top:200px;">
```

...over this (your first example):

```
<body class="noScroll">
```

...which is obviously removed by the `removeClass(...)` function call.