# Can I use javascript to change individual page css entries (as opposed to swapping stylesheets)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know it's possible to change css attributes on elements on the current page:

```
$('.changeMyStyle').css("color", "#FF0000");
```

But this won't affect new elements added after the change is made.

I know it's possible to [remove, add, or swap out](http://www.cssnewbie.com/simple-jquery-stylesheet-switcher/#.VVZjk5MYF_A) css stylesheets to re-style a page after it's been loaded:

```
$('link.swappableStylesheet').attr('href', 'path/to/new/style.css');
```

But this is a poor solution for changing one or two attributes, especially to programmatically-determined values (such as changing color from a colorpicker).

I could probably [grab a stylesheet's raw data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3164861/1021426), search it, and modify it:

```
var sheet= document.styleSheets[0];
var rules= 'cssRules' in sheet? sheet.cssRules : sheet.rules; // IE compatibility

rules[0].style.padding= '0.32em 2em';
// assumes the first entry in the first stylesheet is the one you want to modify.
// if it's not, you have to search to find the exact selector you're looking for
// and pray it's not in a slightly different order
```

But that's also a poor solution and requires IE-compatibility hacks.

This linked answer also suggests appending another `<style>` element and adding css there. That *could* work for narrow cases, but it's still not ideal (and the answer is 5 years old, so new tools may be available now).

Is there a way to alter the page's css at a selector & attribute level instead of stylesheet level or DOM element level? jQuery and vanilla javascript solutions both welcome, as well as libraries designed to do this specifically. Ideally I'd like something that's as easy and versatile as

```
$(document).stylesheet('.arbitraryCssSelector.Here').put('color', '#FF0000');
```

...where `.stylesheet('.Here.arbitraryCssSelector')` would modify the exact same style entry.

Comment: If you have more than one page, why do you need to use jQuery, why can't you call different CSS?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Not sure where you're getting `have more than one page` from?

Comment: This smells a little like an XY problem. What's wrong with adding a `<style>` element, if you want all current and future items to be styled a certain way?

Comment: Adding a style element or appending to an existing one sounds like an ideal solution to me, not sure why you consider it undesirable.

Comment: @MartinCarney Sorry buddy, the question is unclear for me. Lemme read and reread.

Comment: There's also really not any more options for you out there. Either you modify stylesheets and have to use compatibility hacks, add a new style with style tags, or re-run style settings everytime you add a relative element. I don't think any other choice exists.

Comment: @MartinCarney My question is "Why?" - The whole point to CSS is to allow you flexibility in the display of your content. Could the problem not be solved by extending an element to have the different styles? For example, maybe `$('.changeMyStyle').addClass("red");` instead of `$('.changeMyStyle').css("color", "#FF0000");`?

Comment: @swatkins Not if it's a programatic value (you don't want to add a class for every color combination)

Comment: @J4G For programmatic values, I would then go with Michaels answer and programmatically add/remove style elements to the page.

Comment: @Michael Maybe it is an XY problem, or my Y is a solution looking for a real X case. I've asked myself if there was a way to do this on three or more separate, unrelated occasions, though. And it's clear other people have asked how to do this before. Which I think is why I'm asking now and am not satisfied with the solutions to various X's I've found elsewhere that have asked for this same Y.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want to do, I'd hardcode the styles in a stylesheet and swap `class`es in and out. I'm sure that use cases _exist_ where that's not the answer, but I suspect them to be rare.

Answer (score 2):

Even Chrome's dev tools just modifies the stylesheet it's using when you make modifications or add new rules. There's not currently a way around it, but you can keep a dedicated stylesheet at the bottom of the page that you update with the newest rules. If it's empty or contains invalid rules it will just fall back to the current stylesheet. If any library exists out there this is how it would do it, and it's very little code.

I think the key to keeping it uncluttered is to simply keep overwriting one stylesheet instead of adding new stylesheets to the DOM.

```js
document.getElementById("dynamic-color").addEventListener("input", function () {
  document.getElementById("dynamic-styles").innerHTML = "label { color: " + this.value + " }";
});
```

```css
label {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<label for="#dynamic-color">Change the label's color!</label>
<input id="dynamic-color" />

<style id="dynamic-styles"></style>
```