# Remove CSS properties that were set in a CSS file (not inline CSS) [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a CSS property that was set in a stylesheet file:

```
.main-outer-div-filter {
    max-height: 230px;
}
```

I am trying to remove it with jQuery like so:

```
$('.main-outer-div-filter').css('max-height','');
```

For some reason, this way doesn't seem to have any affect, it only works if I set the style inline, but not when it is in the CSS file.
Is there any way to use jQuery to reset/remove CSS properties, which were set in a CSS file?

Thank you

Comment: Use classes instead of that, you can't reset CSS proprieties to initial values

Comment: you can overwrite css from jQuery with !important

Comment: jQuery's `.css()` method adds inline style to the matched elements. Since the specificity value of inline style is higher than any CSS selectors, it should get applied actually. I suggest you have a look to your web browser devtools to figure it out. As an aside, in the context of CSS it is called a property, not an attribute.

Comment: By any chance, if you want to modify the external stylesheet in DOM, you can use `document.styleSheets` object (along with its methods). But jQuery doesn't provide any tools for that. Therefore you should do it with pure JavaScript.

Comment: @HashemQolami that's amazing, should write this as an answer...

Comment: @CreativeMind I think it is already answered on S.O. You might want to have a look at: [Can jQuery change css style definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164740/can-jquery-change-css-style-definition-not-individual-css-of-each-element) topic. You could also find some examples [here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript).

Answer (score 4):

With `('max-height', '')` you are removing inline css. That would work if you set it inline before. To reset it, use `initial` value:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.special').css({
    'max-height': 'initial'
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Max-height: 20px;</li>
  <li class="special">Max-height: initial;</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite a property with inline style using jQuery, as you are doing now, only you need to set this property to something. If you have a `max-height` set to 230px and want it to reset completely, then use `'max-height', 'none'`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use new class name to override it:

```
.main-outer-div-filter {
    max-height: 230px;
}
.main-outer-div-filter.override {
    max-height: initial; /* or none; */
}
```

and in the js you can set it with:

```
$('.main-outer-div-filter').addClass('override');
```

Comment: yes, he could use new classes or inline CSS, as I believe he knows, but that's not the question

Comment: @AnnieTrubak then the answer is very short: **No!! can't be done.**